# ab (Apache Bench) issues on OS X

Tags: performance, macos, apache, apachebench

I am having frustrating issues with trying to perform a highly concurrent test using [ab (apache bench)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) on OS X.  A snippet of the output looks like:

```
Completed 1998 requests
Completed 2664 requests
Completed 3330 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

The command I am running is something like: (I would like the concurrency to be even higher! My goal is to get at least 20,000 rpm to hit the server)

```
ab -k -r -c 400 -n 60000 [URL HERE]
```

Has anyone run into this -- love a push in the right direction?  And I would love to do this on my mac.

#### My Environment:

- OS X : 10.6.8
- httpd : Apache/2.2.20 (Unix)

  - Architecture:   64-bit
  - Server MPM:     Prefork
  - threaded:     no
  - forked:     yes (variable process count)
- ab : Version 2.3  (built from latest apache http beta)
- ulimit -a yields:

  - core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
  - data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  - file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  - max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
  - max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  - open files                      (-n) 1024
  - pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
  - stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  - cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  - max user processes              (-u) 266
  - virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an awesome utility that solved my problem elegantly:

Bees with Machine Guns!!

Repository: https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns

Blog entry about it: http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2010/07/08/bees-with-machine-guns/

Answer (score 0):

For testing on something other than amazon, I used jMeter, and it worked great.  But I would like to find out what exactly the ab problem is.